# zero_output_for_mask RNN backend parameter not present in Keras

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tf.keras

I am using LSTM layers in `tf.keras` and I am trying to build an identical LSTM layer in `keras`.

I noticed that `tf.keras.backend.rnn` has a parameter `zero_output_for_mask` [link](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.13/api_docs/python/tf/keras/backend/rnn). I understand that this parameter (if True) says to use an array of 0s when a timestep is missed/skipped, and (if False) says to use the previous output of the LSTM when a timestep is missed/skipped. I do not see this parameter in Keras RNN layers [link](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/95fab0e01d0451b70ee7b45469242438fefdb1cb/keras/layers/recurrent.py#L239).

I am wondering if the default behavior of `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` with `zero_output_for_mask=False` (the default behavior) is the same as the default behavior of `keras.layers.LSTM`? If not, how do I replicate the behavior of `tf.keras.layers.LSTM` in `keras.layers.LSTM`?